# Do you know of an example of Grails and neo4j configuration?

Tags: grails, neo4j

There is a Grails and neo4j plugin that says that GORM is supported however the docs are somewhat old and I can't get it working.

Running the grails3-gorm sample from the distribution under Grails 5.0.0 RC1 yields the exception below:

```
C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\gorm-neo4j\examples\grails3-neo4j>grails -version
| Grails Version: 5.0.0.RC1
| JVM Version: 15
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...

> Configure project :
GORM VERSION = 7.1.0.RC2

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

| Running application...
GORM VERSION = 7.1.0.RC2
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/neo4j/Neo4jHealthContributorConfigurations$Neo4jConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'neo4jHealthContributor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.DatastoreConfigurationException: Embedded Neo4j server was configured but 'neo4j-harness' classes not found on classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:485)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:472)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
        at functional.tests.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/neo4j/Neo4jHealthContributorConfigurations$Neo4jConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'neo4jHealthContributor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.DatastoreConfigurationException: Embedded Neo4j server was configured but 'neo4j-harness' classes not found on classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/neo4j/Neo4jHealthContributorConfigurations$Neo4jConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'neo4jHealthContributor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.DatastoreConfigurationException: Embedded Neo4j server was configured but 'neo4j-harness' classes not found on classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.healthContributorRegistry(HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:82)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.DatastoreConfigurationException: Embedded Neo4j server was configured but 'neo4j-harness' classes not found on classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1598)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1562)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.DatastoreConfigurationException: Embedded Neo4j server was configured but 'neo4j-harness' classes not found on classpath.
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
        ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.DatastoreConfigurationException: Embedded Neo4j server was configured but 'neo4j-harness' classes not found on classpath.
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.connections.Neo4jConnectionSourceFactory.create(Neo4jConnectionSourceFactory.java:85)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.connections.Neo4jConnectionSourceFactory.create(Neo4jConnectionSourceFactory.java:30)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.neo4j.Neo4jDatastore.<init>(Neo4jDatastore.java:228)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor35.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208)
        ... 71 common frames omitted
<=============> 100% EXECUTING [1m 12s]
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
Note: C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\gorm-neo4j\grails-datastore-gorm-neo4j\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\org\grails\datastore\gorm\neo4j\GraphPersistentEntity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':examples-grails3-neo4j:bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Tools\java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with | Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GORM Neo4J project has an example subproject which use Neo4j as primary data source, please check https://github.com/grails/gorm-neo4j/tree/master/examples/grails3-neo4j for more informaiton.

Here is an example https://github.com/puneetbehl/neo4j-example

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that I'll check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with current versions of Grails or neo4j :(

Comment: The examples should be working because we run all the tests before publishing and all tests are green https://github.com/grails/gorm-neo4j/actions/runs/1186828519. Are you still seeing the same error as stated above?

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect the exception I get when running the grails3-gorm sample from the command line under Grails 5.0.0RC1.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for that. Can you put this as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Gradle didn't find org.grails.plugins:neo4j:7.1.0.RC3 so I specified the version in build.gradle to org.grails.plugins:neo4j:7.1.0.RC2 and was able to get it running.

Comment: I have updated the current answer with link to sample application.